Applying a Laplacian operator to a complex scalar and its complex conjugate
In a course I'm following, a derivation of the continuity equation $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \vec{j}= 0$ is introduced with the following steps.
We have the derivative of the probability density of a particle in a spherical volume using the Born Rule:

$\dot{P_V} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_V |\Psi|^2d^3r $


$= \int_V [(\dot{\Psi^C} \Psi ) + (\Psi^C\dot{\Psi})]d^3r$

Where here I represent $\Psi^C$ as the complex conjugate of $\Psi$ (as * looks messy as the exponent of Psi in LaTeX). We find via the Schrodinger Equation the values of $\dot{\Psi}$ and its complex conjugate:

$\dot{\Psi}=\frac{-i}{\hbar}\widehat{H}\Psi$


$\dot{\Psi^C}=\frac{i}{\hbar}\widehat{H}\Psi^C$

My issue arises from when we plug these values into the integral $\dot{P_V}$:

$\dot{P_V} = \int_V [\frac{i}{\hbar}(\widehat{H}\Psi^C)\Psi  - \frac{i}{\hbar}\Psi^C(\widehat{H}\Psi)]d^3r$

Wherein we substitute the Hamiltonian $\widehat{H} = \widehat{k} + u$, for $\widehat{k} = \frac{\widehat{p}^2}{2m} = -\frac{\hbar^2 \nabla^2}{2m}$ to eventually land us at

$\dot{P_V} = -\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\int_V [(\nabla^2\Psi^C)\Psi  - \Psi^C(\nabla^2\Psi)]d^3r$

My question specifically is why these two terms in the integral do not cancel out. The course gave a very brief introduction to the Laplacian operator $\Delta = \nabla^2$, but taught none of its properties. How exactly does the double gradient operate here, and why does it not result in a cancellation to zero within the volume integral?
(Apologies if some of my latex is hard to read, I'm new at this.)

Note that $$-i[(\nabla^2\Psi^C)\Psi  - \Psi^C(\nabla^2\Psi)] = \Im [(\nabla^2\Psi^C)\Psi ].$$ So the integrand will not vanish if $(\nabla^2\Psi^C)\Psi $ has a non-zero imaginary part.  With this in mind it's not hard to find a function where the integrand does not vanish;  $\Psi = 1 + \frac{i}{2} x^2$ fits the bill.



$\dot{P_V} = -\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\int_V [(\nabla^2\Psi^C)\Psi  - \Psi^C(\nabla^2\Psi)]d^3r$

My question specifically is why these two terms in the integral do not cancel out.

They do not cancel because they are not the same, unless $\Psi$ is real. (Or certain other special circumstances that can be seen from the below discussion.)

Anyways, since $\Psi$ is generally complex, you can write:
$$
\Psi = f + ig\;,
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are real.
Thus
$$
\Psi^C = f-ig
$$
and thus
$$
[(\nabla^2\Psi^C)\Psi  - \Psi^C(\nabla^2\Psi)]
$$
$$
=(\nabla^2f - i\nabla^2g)(f+ig)  - (f-ig)(\nabla^2f + i\nabla^2g)
$$
$$
=f\nabla^2 f +ig\nabla^2f -if\nabla^2g +g\nabla^2g
-(f\nabla^2f + if\nabla^2g -ig\nabla^2f +g\nabla^2g)
$$
$$
=+2i(g\nabla^2f -f\nabla^2g)\;,
$$
which is not zero unless
$$
g\nabla^2f -f\nabla^2g\tag{1}
$$
is zero, which is generally not true. But, for example, if $g=0$ so that $\Psi$ is real, then Eq. (1) is zero.

UPDATE, from comments:

"I believe this would be a restatement of my original problem -- why aren't the terms in (1) equal? Given that it seems like two real scalars multiplied by a vector, I'd imagine they'd be equivalent and thus equal zero."

Thus, it seems like OP is actually confused about the meaning of the $\nabla$ operator. So, it turns out this is not really a physics question, but rather a basic confusion in differential calculus.
The $\nabla^2$ symbol represents a differential operator and can not be "commuted" like a non-operator symbol. That is, in general:
$$
f\nabla^2 g \neq g\nabla^2 f\;.
$$
For example, if
$$
f=x^2
$$
and
$$
g=x^3
$$
then
$$
\nabla^2 f = 2
$$
and
$$
\nabla^2 g = 6x
$$
and
$$
f\nabla^2 g - g\nabla^2f = 6x^3 - 2x^3 = 4x^3 \neq 0
$$

I believe this would be a restatement of my original problem -- why aren't the terms in (1) equal? Given that it seems like two real scalars multiplied by a vector, I'd imagine they'd be equivalent and thus equal zero.

"Given that it seems like two real scalars multiplied by a vector"  $f$ and $g$ are functions and $\nabla$ is a differential operator. You can't just "commute" the $\nabla^2$ operator like you can with non-operators. @umntc

I think it's safe to assume that I'm not the smartest man alive.
